# generating functions and the sequence $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+\frac{1}{x_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

- I start learning about generating functions , so I ask , for example , what all the deduces that a generatingfunctionologist can make for a sequence like :
- $x_{0}= c$ (some constant ,  say for example 1).
- $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+\frac{1}{x_{n}}$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/29777/1102

Comment: @Aryabhata, Grrrr... I spent the last 10 minutes of my life searching for this page, finally found it, and came back on this one to discover your comment. :-)

Comment: @Didier: Sorry :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure that generating functions enter the picture here but the asymptotics of $(x_n)$ is clear: first prove that $x_n\to+\infty$, then note that $x_{n+1}^2=x_n^2+2+1/x_n^2$, and that this implies first that $x_n^2=2n+o(n)$ and then that $x_n^2=2n+\frac12\log n+o(\log n)$.