# $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$ where $a_{1}=1$. Is $f(n)=a_n$ an elementary function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a closed form for this sequence: $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_n^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/find-a-closed-form-for-this-sequence-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1)

Suppose $$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$ where $a_{1}=1$. Is $f(n)=a_n$ an elementary function?

I haven't found any paper concerning it. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: You might be interested in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190190313).

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63549/generating-functions-and-the-sequence-x-n1-x-n-frac1x-n

Comment: @J.M. Thanks a lot!

Comment: the elementariness remain unknown

Comment: The paper proposed by @J.M. 'The Fractional Chromatic Number Of Mycielski's Graphs' is available at [CiteSeer](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.40.4280).

Comment: References at http://oeis.org/A073833

Comment: I know some of the closed form such as $\sqrt{2n+\frac{\log{n}}{2}}$, but I need the elementariness of function $f$, not the upper/lower bound or equivalent infinite