# Let $x_0 = 1, x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{x_n}$; let $y_n = x_n^2 - 2n$ , show that $y_n$ is monotone increasing and $y_n < \log n + 2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For the question as in the title, I have found that the sequence $x_n$ diverges, and I have come up with a recursive formula for $y_n$ as $y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{1}{y_n + 2n}$; but I am struggling to find a way to prove $y_n < 2 + \log n$, and finally the question requires to prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n - \sqrt{2n} = 0$, which I think will depend on the previous inequality I'm struggling to prove.

Can anyone offer some hint on how I should proceed?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4086273/629362)

Comment: Have you tried induction?

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/closed-form-for-the-sequence-defined-by-a-0-1-and-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1)

Comment: I attempted induction at first, but the $2n$ term in the denominator of the recurrence relation seems to make things more complicated...

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks the link really helps! Now I've figured it out!