# Is the following limit finite ....?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

I would like to see some clue for the following problem:

Let $a_1=1$ and $a_n=1+\frac{1}{a_1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{a_{n-1}}$, $n>1$. Find
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n-\sqrt{2n}\right).
$$

Comment: Notice that $a_n=a_{n-1}+1/a_{n-1}$ and read the "Babylonian method" in [this Wiki article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Comment: @mathbeing according to this ${a_n} $ converges to 2?

Comment: No, $a_n$ must diverge to $+\infty$, and I suspect that $\lim_n(a_n-\sqrt{2n})=0$, but I wasn't able to prove it so far. Actually I am no longer sure that the link I posted can be of much help... In what context did you find this question?

Comment: Let $f(x)=2 \cosh(\ln(x))$ and $f^{oh}(x)$ the *h'th* iterate, then $f^{on}(1)=a_{n+1}$ For large $x$ the $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ are neighboured and roughly $0.5 \exp(x)$   Perhaps one can do something for the proof from this ...

Comment: @J.B.Bastos possible duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128325/solution-to-the-recurrence-relation-x-n1-x-n-frac1x-n-derivation/2130284), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2110178/a-general-term-formula-of-such-a-nonlinear-recursion-formula), or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2111037/if-a-n1-a-n1-a-n-and-a-0-1-show-a-n-h-n4-to-infty-but-a-n-h-n4).

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you, I was not aware of any of those. I am ending the bounty...

Comment: No worries -- I mostly linked them for indexing and search purposes.

Answer (score 11):

The recurrence can be re-written as $a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac1{a_n}$. Let $x_n=a_n^2$; then we have $x_1=1$ and
$$
x_{n+1} = a_{n+1}^2 = \left(a_n+\dfrac1{a_n}\right)^2 = 
a_n^2+2+\dfrac1{a_n^2} = x_n+2+\dfrac1{x_n}.
$$
From this we can conclude $x_{n+1}>x_n+2$, so
$$ x_n \ge 2n-1; $$
then $x_{n+1}=x_n+2+\dfrac1{x_n}<x_n+2+\dfrac1{2n-1}$, so
$$ 
x_n < 2n-1 + \left(1+\dfrac13+\dfrac15+\ldots+\dfrac1{2n-3}\right)
< 2n+\log n.
$$
Finally,
$$
\big|a_n-\sqrt{2n}\big| = \dfrac{|a_n^2-2n|}{a_n+\sqrt{2n}} <
\dfrac{|x_n-2n|}{\sqrt{2n}} < \dfrac{\log n}{\sqrt{2n}}.
$$
Therefore,
$\big|a_n-\sqrt{2n}\big|\to0$.

Comment: trivial induction

Comment: Only one thing is not clear to me. The inequality of the 7th line of this paragraph, which involves logarithm

Comment: $1+\frac13+\frac15+\ldots+\frac1{2n-3} < 1+\frac12+\frac13+\ldots+\frac1{n-1}<1+\log(n-1)$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that the sequence is a [**Newton–Raphson method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method)
for calculating numerically the zeroes of a function. What would that function look like then?
$$
x_{n+1}=x_{n}-{\frac {f(x_{n})}{f'(x_{n})}} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}
$$
Identify $\,a_n = x_n\,$ in the first place, and solve for the function:
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = -x \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad f(x) = C\,e^{-x^2/2}
$$
Interpretation: the sequence is a Newton–Raphson iterative method : for finding the zeroes of a Gaussian.
However, it is clear from the start that the numerical calculations are not going to find those zeroes,
for the simple reason that there aren't any.

[image]

But suppose that we modify the problem a bit, as follows: find the zeroes of $\;f(x) = e^{-x^2/2} - e^{-N}\;$
with $N$ some large positive integer, then we have instead the sequence:
$$
x_{n+1}=x_{n}+\frac{1}{x_n}\left[1-\frac{e^{-N}}{e^{-x_n^2/2}}\right]
$$
And now the iterations stop when:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad e^{-x_n^2/2} = e^{-N} \quad \Longleftrightarrow \quad
x_n = \sqrt{2N}
$$
Here is a little (Delphi Pascal) program that does the job:

```
program Diego;

procedure main(N : integer);
var
  x,y : double;
  t : integer;
begin
  Writeln('sqrt(2N) =',sqrt(2*N));
  x := 1; y := 0; t := 0;
  Writeln(t:4,' : x =',x);
  while not (y=x) do
  begin
    y := x; t := t + 1;
    x := x + 1/x*(1-exp(-N)/exp(-sqr(x)/2));
    Writeln(t:4,' : x =',x);
  end;
end;

begin
  main(8);
end.
```

Output:

```
sqrt(2N) = 4.00000000000000E+0000
   0 : x = 1.00000000000000E+0000
   1 : x = 1.99944691562985E+0000
   2 : x = 2.49834687643857E+0000
   3 : x = 2.89556809260418E+0000
   4 : x = 3.23325795454623E+0000
   5 : x = 3.52322153181656E+0000
   6 : x = 3.75982762597611E+0000
   7 : x = 3.92105171808397E+0000
   8 : x = 3.98953172402065E+0000
   9 : x = 3.99979758749457E+0000
  10 : x = 3.99999992320208E+0000
  11 : x = 3.99999999999999E+0000
  12 : x = 4.00000000000000E+0000
  13 : x = 4.00000000000000E+0000
```

So far so good. Now, what will happen if the value of $N$ is increased indefinitely?
Then the sequence will become longer and longer; in the end it will never stop.
Moreover, the following will be true:
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} e^{-N} = 0  \quad \Longrightarrow \quad x_{n+1}=x_{n}+\frac{1}{x_n}
$$
It is clearly seen, however, that the number of iterations in the finite case ($n = 13$)
*does not equal* $N = 8$ . So I doubt if the conjectured limit is true. Still apart 
from the fact that subtraction of two (infinitely) large numbers is highly unstable numerically (i.e. "bad" limit).

**Update.** Further numerical experiments reveal that indeed our iterands $\,x_n\,$ as well as the OP's original $\,a_n\,$
are close to $\,\sqrt{2n}\,$ and the larger $\,n\,$ the better, it seems. Here is an example, with $\,\sqrt{2\times 8192} = 128$ :

```
8188 : x = 1.27991318734407E+0002 , a = 1.27993080007178E+0002
8189 : x = 1.27996559906482E+0002 , a = 1.28000892929564E+0002
8190 : x = 1.27999342587009E+0002 , a = 1.28008705375065E+0002
8191 : x = 1.27999973101217E+0002 , a = 1.28016517343767E+0002
8192 : x = 1.27999999953749E+0002 , a = 1.28024328835758E+0002 <==
8193 : x = 1.27999999999999E+0002 , a = 1.28032139851126E+0002
8194 : x = 1.28000000000000E+0002 , a = 1.28039950389958E+0002
8195 : x = 1.28000000000000E+0002 , a = 1.28047760452340E+0002
```

So it may be conjectured that for all $\,n$ :
$$
x_n < \sqrt{2n} < a_n
$$
With:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{x_n}\left[1 - \frac{e^{-n}}{e^{-x_n^2/2}}\right]
\quad ; \quad a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}
$$
I have not (yet) been able to prove that this conjecture is true.

Comment: Your approach is very interesting. It constitude a numerical method, I'll try to develop the ideas behind.

Answer (score 4):

As other answers indicate, this sequence obeys to the following recurrence relation :

$$a_1=1\quad\mathrm{and}\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$

This proves that the sequence is increasing. Supposing its convergence to some finite limit $L>0$ would lead to $L=L+\dfrac{1}{L}$, a contradiction.
Hence the sequence diverges towards $+\infty$.

Now, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have :

$$a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2=\left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^2-a_n^2=2+\frac{1}{a_n^2}\longrightarrow 2$$

By Cesaro's lemma :

$$\frac{1}{n}\left(a_n^2-a_0^2\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(a_{k+1}^2-a_k^2\right)\longrightarrow 2$$

Thus $$a_n\sim\sqrt{2n}$$ Now, we will use ...

**Lemma** *Given a sequence $(u_n)_{n\ge1}$ of positive real numbers such that $u_n\sim\dfrac{1}{n}$, we have :*
$$\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\sim\ln(n)$$

(See below for a proof.)

Since $a_{n+1}^2-a_n^2-2\sim\dfrac{1}{2n}$ and by the previous lemma :

$$a_n^2-2n\sim\frac{\ln(n)}{2}$$

which can be written :

$$a_n=\sqrt{2n}\,\sqrt{1+\frac{\ln(n)}{4n}+o\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)}$$

Using now the Taylor expansion $\sqrt{1+t}=1+\frac{t}{2}+o(t)$ as $t\to0$, we get finally :

$$\boxed{a_n=\sqrt{2n}\left(1+\frac{\ln(n)}{8n}+o\left(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\right)\right)}$$

In particular, we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n-\sqrt{2n}\right)=0$, but the result above is much more accurate.

---

**Proof of the above lemma**

Given $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ such that :

$$k>N\implies\left|u_k-\frac{1}{k}\right|\le\epsilon$$

As soon as $n>N$, we have :

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^nu_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right|\le\underbrace{\left|\sum_{k=1}^N\left(u_k-\frac{1}{k}\right)\right|}_{=A}+\sum_{k=N+1}^n\left|u_k-\frac{1}{k}\right|\le A+\epsilon\sum_{k=N+1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$

And a fortiori :

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^nu_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right|\le A+\epsilon\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=+\infty$, there exists $N'\in\mathbb{N}^\star$ such that :

$$n>N'\implies\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}>\frac{A}{\epsilon}$$

Finally :

$$n>\max\{N,N'\}\implies\left|\sum_{k=1}^nu_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right|\le2\epsilon\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$

This proves that :

$$\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\sim\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$

But we know that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\sim\ln(n)$ as $n\to\infty$, hence the conclusion (by transitivity of $\sim$).

Comment: Using Stolz's theorem, the  proof of $\sum_{k=1}^nu_k\sim\ln(n),n\to\infty$ will be easy!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution: let us assume that there exists a real number $S $ such that 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a_n-S\sqrt{2n} \right)=0$$

If this constant (and necessarily positive) value exists, we should be able to determine it. On the other hand, if such constant value does not exist (for example, if $S $ is not a constant but a function of $n $), we could expect some contradiction.

Under the assumption that a real $S $ exists, we have

$$  \lim_{n\to\infty}   \frac {1}{a_n}=  \lim_{n\to\infty}    \frac {1}{S \sqrt {2n}}$$

Also, because by definition the recurrence of the OP can be written as $a_{n+1}=a_n+1/a_n \,\, \,\,$, we have

$$  \lim_{n\to\infty}   \frac {1 }{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( a_{n+1}-a_n \right) \\ =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( S \sqrt {2(n+1)} -S  \sqrt {2n}\right) $$

Combining the two equations above we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac {1}{S \sqrt {2n}}= \lim_{n\to\infty} S \left( \sqrt {2(n+1)} -  \sqrt {2n} \right)$$

Solving for $S $ and taking into account that $S$ cannot be negative,  we obtain

$$S= \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac { \sqrt {n+1}  +  \sqrt {n}}{2 \sqrt {n} } = 1$$

Thus, assuming existence of real $S $, we obtain $S=1\,\,$ with no contradiction. We conclude that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(a_n-\sqrt{2n} \right)=0$$

It should be pointed out that this solution does not give a proof that such limit exists, but only shows that, assuming its existence, it must be $1$.

Comment: I kinda like your answer, but I don't see how it proves the existence of the limit. Clearly we can expect some contradiction if we assume there is not such constant $S$, but you haven't found any, so, unless it is implicitly implied and I am missing something, your answer does not provide a proof of the existence of the limit. (?)

Comment: I'm not sure I'm convinced by this argument. You have not found a contradiction, true, but I don't think you've shown that a contradiction doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I fully agree with you. The solution was not provided to give a proof that such limit exists, but only to confirm that, if such value $S $ exists, it must be $1$. Sorry for not having better clarified this when highlighting the assumption at the beginning of the answer.     Probably, repeating the steps assuming non-existence of such  $S $ could lead us to a contradiction. I will try it.

Comment: I edited my  answer to better clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and dirty proof.**
Assume for a moment that the sequence $\,a_n\,$ is a continuous
and differentiable function $\,a(n)\,$ of $\,n\,$ as is suggested in the picture below.
[image]

Then consider the following sequence. Fasten your seatbelts!
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} \\
\frac{a_{n+1} - a_n}{1} = \frac{1}{a_n} \\
\frac{a(n+dn) - a(n)}{dn} = \frac{1}{a(n)} \\
a'(n)\,a(n) = 1 \\ \frac{da^2(n)}{dn} = 2 \\
a^2(n) = 2n+C
$$
[Scaling argument deleted. I see no way to get it consistent, let it be rigorous. See edits of this post]
Now we would like to have $\,C=0$ ; and fortunately there is a boundary condition, for $\,n=2$ , that fits the bill : $\,C = a_2^2 - 2\cdot 2 = 0$ . So:
$\;a_n = \sqrt{2n}$ .
The larger $n$ , the better all of the approximations. A much neater way to express the end-result is:
$$
\large \boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{2n}} = 1}
$$
BONUS. Lemma:
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
a_{n-1}^2 - a_na_{n-1} + 1 = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a_{n-1} = \frac{a_n}{2} + \sqrt{\left(\frac{a_n}{2}\right)^2-1}
$$
Now compute (the discretization of) the second derivative, assuming again that $\,a_n\,$ is large:
$$
a''(n) = a_{n+1} - 2a_n + a_{n-1} = a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} - 2a_n + \frac{a_n}{2} +
\frac{a_n}{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(a_n/2)^2}} \approx \\ \frac{1}{a_n} - \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{a_n}{2}
\left[1-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(a_n/2)^2} - \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{(a_n/2)^2}\right)^2\right] = -\frac{1}{a_n^3}
$$
Which means that the discrete function $\,a_n\,$ for large $\,n\,$ is actually *very smooth* , when seen as a continuous
and differentiable $\,a(n)$ . This is an even stronger motivation for the above treatment.
It is noticed that the "true" derivatives exhibit the same structure as the discretizations:
$$
\left(\sqrt{2x}\right)'' = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x}}\right)' = -\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{2x}\right)^3}
$$
There are no coincidences in mathematics.