# General term for a nonlinear recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'd like to know the general term of the following recurrence
$$a_{n+1}=a_n + \frac{\alpha}{a_n}, $$
where $\alpha>0$ and $a_0=M>0$. That is, ideally I'd like to find the function $g$ such that $a_n = g(n;\alpha,M)$.
Any idea? Many thanks !

Comment: Here is an idea that may not work for your case but nails it if $$a_{n+1} = \frac12\left( a_n+ \frac{\alpha}{a_n}\right)$$ Let $a_n = \tanh z$, then you will find something like $a_{n+1} = \tanh (2z)$ and the closed form becomes easy. (If $\alpha < 0$ use $\tan z$ instead.) The idea does not work unchanged, but may provide a starting point.

Comment: With $\,a_n = \sqrt{\alpha} \,b_n\,$ the recurrence becomes $b_{n+1} = b_n + \cfrac{1}{b_n}\,$. Maybe relevant: [Closed form for the sequence defined by $a_0=1$ and $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_n^{-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/closed-form-for-the-sequence-defined-by-a-0-1-and-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1).

Comment: Many thanks! Yes @dxiv that discussion was very helpful