# Show that a recursive sequence converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I want to answer the following question:

A real sequence defined by $x_{n+1}=x_{n}+x_{n}^{-1}, \ x_1 >0$ converges?

I think it's not true, but I can't find a counterexample. Can someone help me?

Comment: why do you think it is not true?

Comment: Think about what is happening to the terms. Are they increasing or decreasing? Consider different starting numbers for $x_1$

Comment: I think it's not true because the terms are increasing.

Comment: @ivmat That doesn't necessarily imply divergence: consider the sequence $a_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact it isn't because if $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n=L\in \Bbb R$ then

$$x_{n+1}=x_{n}+x_{n}^{-1}$$

would give you (when you make $n\to \infty$)

$$L=L+L^{-1}\to L^{-1}=0$$

what is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$x_{n+1}^2 = x_n^2+2+\frac{1}{x_n^2} > x_n^2+2.$$

Comment: In fact, this helped me to bootstrap to convince myself $x_n \sim \sqrt{2n}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/closed-form-for-the-sequence-defined-by-a-0-1-and-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1?noredirect=1&lq=1