# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

> **Question:** $x_1>0$, $x_{n+1}=x_n+\dfrac1{x_n}$, $n\in\Bbb N$. Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}.$$

What I know now is that $\dfrac1{x_n}\to\dfrac12$ when $n\ge2$,
 $\{x_n\}$ is monotonically increasing，$x_n\ge 2$ when $n\ge 2$.

I have tried to use the Stolz theorem, and I found I could not use Squeeze theorem.

Could you please give some instructions? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/closed-form-for-the-sequence-defined-by-a-0-1-and-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$x_{n+1}^2=\left(x_n+\frac1{x_n}\right)^2=x_n^2+\frac1{x_n^2}+2\implies x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2=\frac1{x_n^2}+2.$$

Obviously, $x_n$ is increasing and $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. Apply the Stolz theorem,
\begin{align*}
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}\right)^2&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2}{n}\\
(\text{Stolz})&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n^2-x_{n-1}^2}{n-(n-1)}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac1{x_{n-1}^2}+2\right)=0+2=2.
\end{align*}
$$\therefore \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}=\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: Thank you! Thank you for telling me a important way to solve such problem is to square the expression.

Answer (score 5):

Hint. Your are not correct, because $x_n\to+\infty$. Moreover, we have that
$$\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{x_n}.$$
So, by Stolz-Cesaro, if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}=L$, then
$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}
\frac{x_{n+1}-x_n}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{x_n}=\frac{2}{L}.$$

Comment: I got it.Thanks,Mr.Robert.Z, I found your approach is similar to @Tianlalu fundamentally. You all used a certain value to subsitute the limit of that expression, and I can get the answer just by solving an equation! Thank you for you instruction again!