# Find the general formula of $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find a closed form for this sequence: $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_n^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29777/find-a-closed-form-for-this-sequence-a-n1-a-n-a-n-1)

If a sequence is defined as  $ a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{a_{n}} $

where $a_1 = 1$

Find the general value of $a_n$ as $f(n)$

Thanks

Comment: What is $a_0$ ?

Comment: So you're looking for a closed (non-recursive) form for your $a_n$. To get there, you're really going to need an initial value ($a_0$ or $a_1$), as Teddy points out.

Comment: Hey! I included the required initial value.

Comment: and also this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10065/

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it exists, see:

http://oeis.org/A073833

Comment: But no answer seems to justify the generalization of that sequence or how it came.